# Expanding array notation in javascript

Tags: javascript

How does the following code work?

```
array=[1,2,3];

Math.max(array)
NaN

Math.max(...array)
3
```

Why can't I do `max` on an array? And what does the `...` notation do? Is that common, or a short-form for something else (like the ternary operator?).

Comment: Look up the docs for `Math.max`. It does not accept an array, so you can't pass it an array (meaningfully). `...` is spread syntax

Comment: See [*MDN: Spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), also [*ECMA-262: SpreadElement*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#prod-SpreadElement).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) only accepts values, not arrays, and when you use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`), you are providing those values, and that's why it works:

```js
array=[1,2,3];

Math.max(...array) // Math.max(1, 2, 3)

console.log(Math.max(array)) // NaN
console.log(Math.max(...array)) // 3
console.log(Math.max(1, 2, 3)) // 3
```

If you need to apply the function `Math.max()` to an array, you'll need to make use of [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```js
array=[1,2,3];
    
Math.max.apply(null, array) // Math.max(1, 2, 3)
    
console.log(Math.max(1, 2, 3)) // 3
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, array)) // 3
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The function `Math.max` only accepts a series of values, not an array.  This `Math.max(...array)` works because the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) "spread" the array using the values within it `->` `Math.max(1, 2, 3)`

If you really need to use the array because the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is not compatible with the current js engine you're using, you can use the function [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, array));
```